# Sonata Admin Bundle: Paginate one-to-many field using sonata_type_collection

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I am using SonataAdminBundle to display one-to-many fields of an entity on the admin panel.

Since I have a lot of related entities I am getting a `503` error when displaying the admin form.

I can override the template to limit the number of children but I would like to load the rest in some sort of pagination.

Is there any way that this can be achieved without breaking the structure of SonataBundle ?

Below is my code:

```
public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{

     $formMapper->add('communityHasMedia', 'sonata_type_collection',[],[
         'edit'     => 'inline',
         'inline'   => 'table',
         'sortable' => 'position',
         'required' => false
     ])
}
```